# How can the dielectric constant of water be so high but water on electric devices can cause a short circuit?

Tags: short-circuit, water, dielectric

Is it only the fact that **pure** water has a high dielectric constant and **non-pure** water i.e. the water that usually causes a short circuit is contaminated and it's the contamination mixture in the water that causes a short circuit?

Comment: The title of the question should be "why does impure water conduct electricity so well?". It'd be more of a question for the chemistry.SE site, but to spoiler this: ions. It's ions. They do what the old Greek word *ion* means: they wander, and since they carry a charge, that constitutes a way to conduct electricity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a chemistry question (and can also be easily googled)

Comment: *the contamination mixture in the water that causes a short circuit?* Says who? Water isn't conductive enough to cause a low-resistance short circuit. That is not to say that water isn't a problem, even a small current flowing through water can cause a shock, corrosion and damage.

Comment: Dielectric constant is generally a reflection of the degree to which the molecular structure is polarized. The water molecule is highly polarized, with one end being more positive that the other, although overall it is neutral.

Having polarized molecules does not necessarily mean good conductivity. That depends on charge mobility, either in the form of electrons or ions.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a hypthetical situation.

The dielectric constant of water Dk=80
   vs air=1 vs  FR4= 4.6

Clean rain between exposed power socket > 10M Ohm causing 24uA  leakage @ 240Vac between contacts and some leakage to ground.

Acid Rain between exposed power socket > 1k ohm causing 240mA steam @ 240Vac and salt accumulation when bridged can cause an arc breakdown short overtime burning contact insulation then worse.

In Electronics, it can degrade the performance of high impedance switches from dust & Water to the point of failure within hours.

When clean water gets onto dust boards with the slightly acidic ions of no-clean solder flux it can corrode exposed copper and bridge tracks overnight after it dries or under SMD with trapped dusty water.

The high Dk can also increase signal rise times by up to 80x if spanning the whole track to a ground track and corrupt synchronous operations.